# SwiftUI Checkbox Is Not Displaying The Check Mark When Clicked

Tags: checkbox, swiftui

I generate a dynamic checkbox list

```
struct DemoStatusSearchView: View {

@ObservedObject var myObject = myObject ()

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing:20) {
        Text("My Check Box List")
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        ForEach(myObject.checkBoxList, id:\.id) { item in
            CheckboxField(
                id: item.checkboxDesc ,
                label: item.checkboxDesc ,
                callback: self.checkboxSelected
            )
        }
    }.padding(20)
    
}
```

But when I click on the checkbox, the checkmark is not displayed.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Eg. what is `self.checkboxSelected`, `myObject`...?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I found the problem. its the myObject that is reseting the value to default, causing the checkbox value to reset. If you put your reply in the answer , I will mark it as answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to add the answer yourself as it's you who found it. But if you want this post to be valuable for others, please add the missing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into my code that the view is being refreshed multiple times based on the multiple calls from the view model class. I clearly don't have an idea how the object state is working in the Combine and SwiftUI, this is the root caused of this issue.

Thank you @pawello2222 for posting me to the right direction.